# How to create a UIPickerView in Delphi xe6 for iOS

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

How do I create a UIPickerview in Delphi xe6 for iOS ? When making a selection for a combobox, a UI picker view will appear. How do I create a similar pickerview, but with more control over it? E.g., being able to place it anywhere on the form, customize it, not have to go through a combobox, etc. ?

I have found where in it's unit class where it is created.

**FMX.Listbox**

```
constructor TCustomComboBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  PickerService: IFMXPickerService;
begin
  inherited;
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXPickerService, IInterface(PickerService)) then
  begin
    FListPicker := PickerService.CreateListPicker;
    FListPicker.Parent := Self;
    FListPicker.OnValueChanged := DoOnValueChangedFromDropDownList;
    FListPicker.OnHide := DoClosePicker;
    FListPicker.OnShow := DoPopup;
  end;
  FDropDownKind := TDropDownKind.Custom;
  DropDownCount := 8;
  FItemWidth := 0;
  CanFocus := True;
  FDroppedDown := False;
  FPopup := TPopup.Create(Self);
  FPopup.StyleLookup := 'combopopupstyle';
  FPopup.PlacementTarget := Self;
  FPopup.Stored := False;
  FPopup.Parent := Self;
  FPopup.Locked := True;
  FPopup.DesignVisible := False;
  FPopup.DragWithParent := True;
  FPopup.OnClosePopup := DoClosePopup;
  FPopup.OnPopup := DoPopup;
  FListBox := CreateListBox;
  FListBox.Parent := Popup;
  FListBox.Stored := False;
  FListBox.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
  FListBox.ShowCheckboxes := False;
  FItemIndex := -1;
  SetAcceptsControls(False);
  DropDownKind := TDropDownKind.Native;
end;
```

I don't need the popup, so I then read about accessing properties and methods via a 'hack-ish' kind of way

```
Type
  THackPicker = class(TCustomComboBox);
```

....

```
var
  FListBox : TComboListBox;
begin
    try
      FListBox := THackPicker(FListBox).createListbox;
      FListBox := TCustomComboBox.createListbox;
      FListBox.Parent := Layout1;
      FListBox.Stored := False;
      FListBox.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
      FListBox.Items := ComboBox1.Items;
      FListBox.OnClick := Button2Click;
    except
        on E : Exception do begin
          showMessage(e.Message);
        end;

    end;
end;
```

App crashes here. I'm assuming this is not the correct way to go about it. Any help or direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your app crashes because you're trying to use `FListBox.createListBox` to create `FListBox` (which hasn't been created yet, because the crash happens when you're trying to create it). Either use `FListBox := createListBox` and then typecast `FListBox` after (`THackPicker(FListBox).Whatever := ...`), or create a separate local variable:  `HackPicker: THackPicker;` and then use it instead: `FListBox := createListBox; HackPicker := THackPicker(FListBox); Hackpicker.Whatever := ...`.